# Confluence is crashing upon installation connection refused

Tags: networking, port, confluence

I try to install Confluence and after running the package I start to setup the application and suddenly the server is blocking the port and then I receive connection refused error from the browser. The output of the telnet command is as below: telnet localhost 8085
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...

what can block the port?

Answer (score 0):

By default you need to make sure that port 8090 and 8091 are available in your instance. If you have changed either of these ports you need to make sure that they are available and they are not used by any other applications.

I would also recommend you to ensure that your firewall or antivirus are not blocking either of these ports.

Comment: it was a memory issue .. I solved it and the instance is running now